# How to Summon a Rideable Phantom?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Bedrock Edition,  I can't seem to summon a ridable phantom. I've watched some YouTube videos and tried all the commands that I found using Google, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Phantoms aren't rideable in vanilla Minecraft. Apparently there are add-ons for that

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the commands you've tried and maybe a link to one of the YouTube videos you've watched? As AjPerez said, this may only be accomplished using mods also.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

In [this article](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-to-tame-a-phantom-in-minecraft) is explained how to do it, but you actually need a mod, named [Phantom+](https://mcpedl.com/phantom-plus-addon/).

And in [this Minecraft feedback post](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360045809312-Tame-Ride-Phantom) is suggested to make them rideable, so it seems it's not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can in Java. The command for Java would be

```
summon phantom ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:minecart",Invulnerable:1b}]}
```

This principle is to spawn the phantom with a minecart as its passenger, this way it always stick to the phantom and would not fall off unless the phantom died, which you can fix by killing the minecart entities if phantom is not detected within a certain radius.

I don't really know about Bedrock summon syntax but according to what I know so far you cannot access NBT tags in Bedrock. If all else failed, try execute as phantoms at their position and keep teleporting the nearest minecart to them using tp command. It is certainly not the best way but at least it kinda works.